# Signature of a non-compact manifold

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

Let $v_0,\dots,v_n\in\mathbb{Z}^2$ be integer vectors which satisfy the condition $\det\begin{pmatrix}v_{k-1}&v_k\end{pmatrix}=(-1)^k$, whose relevance will become apparent in a moment. We may then construct a $4$-manifold $M$ as follows.

For $2\leq k\leq n-1$, let $\tilde{M}_k$ be the set of points $(z,w)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ for which $-2\leq|w|^2-|z|^2\leq 2$. For $k=1$, do the same thing except only requiring $|w|^2-|z|^2\leq 2$, and similarly, for $k=n$, only require $-2\leq |w|^2-|z|^2$.

Making use of the determinant condition stated at the beginning, we may write $$\begin{pmatrix}v_{k-1}&v_k\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}v_k&v_{k+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&m_k\end{pmatrix}$$ for some $m_k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Let $M$ be the disjoint union of the sets $\tilde{M}_k$, modulo identifying $(z,w)\in\tilde{M}_{k+1}$ with $((\frac{z}{|z|})^{m_k}w,z)\in\tilde{M}_k$, whenever $|w|^2-|z|^2=-2$.

One way to view $M$ is as an "$\mathbb{R}^4$ with $n$ origins", since it is possible to give a torus action on $M$ whose fixed points are exactly the origins in the sets $\tilde{M}_k$. The manifold $M$ can quite easily be given a natural smooth structure and a natural orientation.

Anyway, I am trying to calculate the topological signature of $M$, and part of this is of course to make sure I am working with the "right" definition of signature. My motivation for doing this is to assume the existence of a Ricci-flat metric on $M$ with appropriate asymptotic structure, in order to apply (a version of) the Hitchin-Thorpe inequality (see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.07248.pdf), Section 6.2). The definition of signature given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(topology)) seems to only discuss the compact case. I highly suspect that the definition of signature in terms of compactly supported cohomology should be the correct one in order to work with the Hitchin-Thorpe inequality I linked (does this seem correct?). In other words, we define the signature $\tau(M)$ as the signature of the bilinear form $H_c^2(M,\mathbb{R})\times H_c^2(M,\mathbb{R})\to H_c^4(M,\mathbb{R})\cong\mathbb{R}$ given by the cup product.

Assuming this is the case, I am a bit stuck on how to calculate this signature, since I'm not an algebraic topologist. Using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence with compact supports, I proved that the dimension of the second compactly supported cohomology of $M$ is $n-1$, which therefore reduces the problem to finding $n-1$ independent generators (for instance, compactly supported closed $2$-forms, if we're working with de Rham cohomology), in order to compute the cup product on those. But I'm having a hard time constructing such generators. Is there any simple approach for this signature calculation that I am missing?

One thing that I noticed is that for each $k\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$, the set of points $(0,w)\in\tilde{M}_k$ together with the set of points $(z,0)\in\tilde{M}_{k+1}$ forms a $2$-sphere $R_k\subseteq M$, and in addition, these $2$-spheres form a basis for the second homology with real coefficients. I got this by simply constructing (non-compactly supported) closed $2$-forms $\omega_k$, such that the integral of $\omega_k$ over $R_l$ is $\delta_{kl}$. Does this help us in any way?

To summarize, I have two main questions:

- Am I working with the right notion of signature?
- How should I approach the calculation of this signature?